# Manipulating boundary conditions of coupled non-linear ODEs using Manipulate and ParametricNDSolve

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, equation-solving, manipulate

I`m trying to plot solutions that are presented for different values of parameter I called "$A$" which appears in the boundary conditions for a system of two coupled nonlinear differential equations, I begin by using ParametricNDSolve:

```
Clear[x, c, h, Derivative]
solM = ParametricNDSolveValue[{h'[x] == -h[x]^2 (c[x]^2 + 10^-11) + 1, c'[x] == -h[x]c[x], h[5] == 5, c[5] == A*Exp[-12.5]}, {h, c}, {x, 1, 10^11}, {A}]
```

In the next step, I want to plot the graphs which correspond to different values of $A$ between 0 and 1 using Manipulate:

```
    Manipulate[ Plot[Evaluate[#[x] & /@ solM[A]], {x, -7, 2}, PlotLegends -> {h, c}, PlotRange -> {{-7, 2}, {0, 2.5}}], {{A, 1}, 0, 1}]
```

But unfortunately, I got only the bar with A with an empty plot with written $aborted in red, as you can see here:

[image]

the red $aborted contains the following errors:

```
General::munfl: 8.80366*10^-155 7.18841*10^-160 is too small to represent as a normalized machine number; precision may be lost.
General::munfl: 2.74821*10^-155 (-1.28871*10^-159) is too small to represent as a normalized machine number; precision may be lost.
General::munfl: 2.74821*10^-155 4.02292*10^-160 is too small to represent as a normalized machine number; precision may be lost.
General::stop: Further output of General::munfl will be suppressed during this calculation.
```

Is there is way to fix it? or a different way to obtain graphs using manipulation of $A$?

Comment: 1. `solM[h, c]` is obviously wrong. 2. `{x, 0, 10^11}` in `Plot` is not proper. Use `{x, -7, 2}` instead of the `PlotRange`.

Comment: @xzczd just fixed it, see the edit

Comment: As mentioned in my last comment, the `solM[h, c]` is obviously wrong. Please read the document of `ParametricNDSolveValue` carefully.

Comment: @xzczd you are right, I miss that, now after fixing it I still have problem..., you can see that in my latest edit

Comment: I bet some of the variables are polluted again. Try `Clear[h, c, x, Derivative]`. And once again, please always pay attention to the color of variables.

Comment: @xzcd I did this but the problem appears again, I put everything in a new notebook and it worked...

Comment: That should not happen, because every notebook is linked to the same kernel by default, so pasting code into new notebook shouldn't fix anything, unless the code in the question is actually different from that in your old notebook.

Comment: @xzczd I understand, The problem occurred when I put instead of $10^-11$ and $10^11$ in my input 0, $\infty$ respectively, and for some reason, it cannot generate a result in this case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

solM = ParametricNDSolve[{
    h'[x] == -h[x]^2 (c[x]^2 + 10^-11) + 1,
    c'[x] == -h[x] c[x],
    h[5] == 5, c[5] == A*Exp[-25/2]}, 
   {h, c}, {x, 1, 10^11}, {A}];

Manipulate[
 Plot[Evaluate[{h[A][x], c[A][x]} /. solM], {x, -7, 2},
  AxesLabel -> {x, None},
  PlotLegends -> Placed[{h[x], c[x]}, {.5, .25}]],
 {{A, 0.5}, 0, 1, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 SynchronousUpdating -> False,
 TrackedSymbols :> {A}]
```

[image]

However, it is not clear why you define the functions in the interval `{x, 1, 10^11}` but then plot in the interval `{x, -7, 2}`